# Getting EOF exception when reading BlockingChannel on Kafka running on SSL / TLS Listener

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

One piece of my code throws the exception EOF when the Kafka broker is listening on SSL with port 9093 , in plaintext listener the code snippet is working fine.

Any ideas what could be wrong here ??

```
     public KafkaMetadataHelper(String kafkaConnect) throws Exception {
    // use lowlevel kafka.api to query consumer group metadata (ie max committed offset)
    String[] hostAndPort = kafkaConnect.split(":");
    String host = hostAndPort[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(hostAndPort[1]);
    channel = new BlockingChannel(host, port,
                                  BlockingChannel.UseDefaultBufferSize(),
                                  BlockingChannel.UseDefaultBufferSize(),
                                  10000);
    channel.connect();
    GroupCoordinatorRequest request = new GroupCoordinatorRequest(MY_GROUP,
                                                                  GroupCoordinatorRequest.CurrentVersion(),
                                                                  correlationId++,
                                                                  MY_CLIENTID);
    channel.send(request);
    GroupCoordinatorResponse metadataResponse = null;
    try {
         metadataResponse = GroupCoordinatorResponse.readFrom(channel.receive().payload());// This is where the exception is thrown 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

The error message which i am getting is this.

```
    java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:103)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:131)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:122)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect over TLS, your client needs some settings ! `BlockingChannel` does not allow the caller to specify any settings.

I suggest you look at `ConsumerGroupCommand.scala` [1] and see how it uses `AdminClient` [2] to retrieve details about consumer groups.

1. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L496
2. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/AdminClient.scala#L197